# C# Detect USB Mouse (Logitech Mouse)

Tags: c#

I have followed a few other questions on this website about detecting mouse state in C#. My first understanding is that mouse detection isn't simple. There aren't native libraries for doing so and that seems kind of weird to me. But I am looking to write a small light weight C# console app, that will eventually be converted to a windows service to detect if my USB Logitech mouse is present.

I have been trying to find ways to disable the touch pad when my mouse is present in Windows 10 and all the guides I follow don't match up for me, so I have decided to build my own small program for it. I am not looking to use a nuget library to achieve this, I want something small and simple here.

I have this current block of code yet I only ever see the Elan device which I believe to be my touch pad.

```
static async Task StartListenForMouseChangeAsync()
{
   await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
          do
          {
             var mouse = new ManagementObjectSearcher("winmgmts:\\.\\root\\CIMV2");
                    mouse.Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PointingDevice");
             var data = mouse.Get();
             foreach (var obj in data)
             {
                foreach (var item in obj.Properties)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} -- {item.Value}");
                }
             }
             Thread.Sleep(5000);
             Console.Clear();
          } while (true);
       }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Availability -- 
Caption -- HID-compliant mouse
ConfigManagerErrorCode -- 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig -- False
CreationClassName -- Win32_PointingDevice
Description -- HID-compliant mouse
DeviceID -- HID\VID_046D&PID_C231\2&AF07C4&0&0000
DeviceInterface -- 162
DoubleSpeedThreshold -- 
ErrorCleared -- 
ErrorDescription -- 
Handedness -- 
HardwareType -- HID-compliant mouse
InfFileName -- msmouse.inf
InfSection -- HID_Mouse_Inst.NT
InstallDate -- 
IsLocked -- 
LastErrorCode -- 
Manufacturer -- Microsoft
Name -- HID-compliant mouse
NumberOfButtons -- 0
PNPDeviceID -- HID\VID_046D&PID_C231\2&AF07C4&0&0000
PointingType -- 2
PowerManagementCapabilities -- 
PowerManagementSupported -- False
QuadSpeedThreshold -- 
Resolution -- 
SampleRate -- 
Status -- OK
StatusInfo -- 
Synch -- 
SystemCreationClassName -- Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName -- MSI
Availability -- 
Caption -- ELAN Input Device
ConfigManagerErrorCode -- 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig -- False
CreationClassName -- Win32_PointingDevice
Description -- ELAN Input Device
DeviceID -- ACPI\ETD0306\4&1464EB1C&0
DeviceInterface -- 1
DoubleSpeedThreshold -- 
ErrorCleared -- 
ErrorDescription -- 
Handedness -- 
HardwareType -- ELAN Input Device
InfFileName -- oem22.inf
InfSection -- ETD_STD_Inst
InstallDate -- 
IsLocked -- 
LastErrorCode -- 
Manufacturer -- ELAN
Name -- ELAN Input Device
NumberOfButtons -- 0
PNPDeviceID -- ACPI\ETD0306\4&1464EB1C&0
PointingType -- 2
PowerManagementCapabilities -- 
PowerManagementSupported -- False
QuadSpeedThreshold -- 
Resolution -- 
SampleRate -- 
Status -- OK
StatusInfo -- 
Synch -- 
SystemCreationClassName -- Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName -- MSI
Availability -- 
Caption -- USB Input Device
ConfigManagerErrorCode -- 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig -- False
CreationClassName -- Win32_PointingDevice
Description -- USB Input Device
DeviceID -- USB\VID_046D&PID_C24A&MI_00\6&2E5B0EB1&0&0000
DeviceInterface -- 162
DoubleSpeedThreshold -- 
ErrorCleared -- 
ErrorDescription -- 
Handedness -- 
HardwareType -- USB Input Device
InfFileName -- input.inf
InfSection -- HID_Inst.NT
InstallDate -- 
IsLocked -- 
LastErrorCode -- 
Manufacturer -- (Standard system devices)
Name -- USB Input Device
NumberOfButtons -- 0
PNPDeviceID -- USB\VID_046D&PID_C24A&MI_00\6&2E5B0EB1&0&0000
PointingType -- 2
PowerManagementCapabilities -- 
PowerManagementSupported -- False
QuadSpeedThreshold -- 
Resolution -- 
SampleRate -- 
Status -- OK
StatusInfo -- 
Synch -- 
SystemCreationClassName -- Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName -- MSI
```

Comment: I think you don't see it because it's not a pointing device but an USB HID device and (again) I think Windows sepparates those, you can mix the data from your code with this example: http://www.expertcore.org/viewtopic.php?t=1472, with both you should be capable of enumerate all mouses.

Comment: The code block from that article I copied and Visual Studio 2017 doesn't recognize Win32 references.

Comment: .... You have the full project linked in the article...

Comment: I am just trying to use their code samples and that doesn't work for me Win32 references my Visual Studio doesn't recognize and I don't want to download their code sample.

Comment: Also, revise your code, your report has TWO mouses, an ELAN mouse (it uses a specific driver) and a generic one, that generic one must be the logitech one, but it says "generic" because you did not installed the mouse's driver

Comment: Download the project and get the Win32 class...

Comment: I did install the drivers, I have them open right now. That sample output is one of three btw, my code runs 3 loops because `data.Count = 3`

Comment: You have detected three mouses then. And even if you have installed the driver it can be reported as a generic device. Just unplug the mouse, read the devices, plug it and read again, you will see a difference of one device. Also, identifying the device through it's name is very prone to fail, if you want to detect a concrete device use it's DeviceID, you can find it under the properties tab of the device properties on the device manager.

Comment: @Gusman I am working my way through this sample right now, please check back later.

Comment: @Gusman Thank you for helping me with better understanding of the data returned I wrote an update that seems to work for me. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code to this solved my problem

```
static async Task StartListenForMouseChangeAsync()
    {
     await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
      do
        {
          Console.Title = "Scanning";
           var mouse = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"winmgmts:\\.\\root\\CIMV2");
            mouse.Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PointingDevice");
            var data = mouse.Get();
            var states = new Boolean[data.Count];
            var props = new List<ManagementBaseObject>();
              foreach (var item in data)
                {
                  props.Add(item);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
                    {
                        states[i] = props[i].Properties["DeviceID"].Value.ToString().StartsWith("USB");
                    }

                    var hasUsbMouse = states.Contains(true);

                    Console.Title = $"Mouse Status: {hasUsbMouse}";

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    Console.Clear();
                } while (true);

            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
```